# Нужны ли кавычки в данном предложении?

Tags: кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли кавычки в этом предложении? И если да, то почему?

*На пляжах региона активизировалась банда “пляжных воришек”.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре Ефремовой:
[воришка](http://endic.ru/efremova/Vorishka-10689.html), м., разг.
**1.** Вор (1), занимающийся мелкими кражами.
**2.** Малолетний вор.

Карманный воришка, вокзальный воришка, поездной воришка, пляжный воришка (тот, который ворует на пляже) — здесь не нужны кавычки, это (думаю, можно так сказать) разновидности воровской специализации. Кроме того, считаю, что слова "на пляжах" — лишние.

Я бы написала так:
**В регионе активизировалась банда пляжных воришек.**

Может Борис Сергеевич прийти, решит, что ты **квартирный воришка**, и заметет тебя в кутузку. [Марина Зосимкина. Ты проснешься. Книга первая (2015)]

> Если не в меру дотошный жандарм или **поездной воришка** проткнет на пробу — просыплется желтый крупнозернистый порошок, который в пшенично-ржаной России вполне сойдет за кукурузную муку (Борис Акунин. Алмазная колесница).

Answer (score 1):

Если только это будет указание на то, что кто-то их так уже называл (В каких-то СМИ, например, тогда это будет цитата, выдержка). А вообще никаких кавычек не надо, это привычное, установившееся название для воров мелких предметов, если они воруют что-то крупное, то их уже называют ворами, а не воришками. Прямое значение слова.